# How to collect strings for i18n from files in different languages with xgettext

Tags: xgettext

By default `xgettext` will guess file type from its extension. However, I have JavaScript files (with `.js` extension) which it doesn't currently understand. So, I have to specify language manually, Java seems like a good choice. But then, I also have Glade files (XML), which obviously cannot be parsed as Java... When I specify multiple `--language` options on command line, only the last seems to have any effect.

It seems to be a non-issue for projects with file types understood by xgettext (e.g. C and Glade).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `--join-existing` option is what I need. I.e. run `xgettext` separately for each language with the same output file, only adding `--join-existing` for each but the first. Note that if output file doesn't have suffix `.pot`, `xgettext` will print a (useless) warning about charset.